# How can I enable the XCTest indicator on XCode 6.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, xcode6.3

As of **XCode 6.2** a **diamond** appeared at left side of the code in the test classes:

[image]

But, as of **XCode 6.3** this appear to be no longer available/visible.

This diamond is used to offer useful inline information about every XCTest and I want it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in the previous Xcode 6.3 , fixed now with the release of Xcode 6.3.1, regarding Apple features in the new release.